# How to combine each element of a Flux with another Flux that needs an element's attribute

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a question about Spring WebFlux and Reactor.
I am trying to code a simple scenario where in a GET endpoint i return a Flux
of DTOs representing entities, and each of these entities has a collection of
other DTOs representing another entity. Here follow the details.

I have two entities, Person and Song, defined as follows:

```
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}

@Data
public class Song {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Long authorId;
}
```

the entities are represented by the following DTOs:

```
@Data
public class SongDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    public static SongDTO from(Song s) {
        // converts Song to its dto
    }
}

@Data
public class PersonDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<SongDTO> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    public static PersonDTO from(Person p, List<Song> songs) {
        // converts person to its dto, invokes SongDTO.from on each song 
        // and adds the result to personDTO.songs
    }
}
```

My services (not shown here for the sake of brevity) do return Mono and Flux.
Then I have the the following RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired PersonService people;
    @Autowired SongService songs;
    
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<PersonDTO> findAllPeople() {
        return people.findAll()
                .map(person -> PersonDTO.from(person, /* HERE */ new ArrayList<>()));
        // TODO: find the songs of each author reactively and put the results in personDTO.songs
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is: how do I

- call songs.findByAuthorId(person.getId())
- convert the returned Flux to a List of SongDTO
- set the list in PersonDTO
  in a reactive way?

I tried to look into Reactor's documentation without success, searched other StackOverflow questions and
the internet at large, but couldn't find anything, most probably because I am
not really sure about how to phrase my search.
Can someone please provide hints?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` + `map`:

```java
people.findAll()
      .flatMap(person -> songs.findByAuthorId(person.getId())
                              .collectList()
                              .map(songList -> PersonDTO.from(person, songList)));
```